# Header - position image next to the navbar and make the image "stick" to it. After that center both elements horizontally at the bottom of the header

Tags: html, css, css-position

It's kinda hard to explain. I have a rather big header with a width of 90% of the document's width. I need to center a navbar horizontally at the bottom of the header together with an image "sticking" to it on the left side. The image itself is somewhat bigger than the navbar so the navbar shouldn't become bigger because of the image. On top of that half of the image should "reach out" of the header so i guess it has something to do with absolute positioning. I know how to position the navbar at the bottom but i don't quiet get how to do the other stuff. I understand that it was a horrible explanation so i drew something to show you what I mean: [DRAWING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNgt0.png)

I hope someone can help me with that.

I tried to kind of do it like this (I know it's not the greatest example but that's how I tried to do it):

```
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #header {
        position: relative;
        width: 80%;
        height: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #main_nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 80%;
    }

    #main_nav > ul {
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main_nav > ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        height: 70px;
        line-height: 70px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .image {
        width: 350px;
        height: 185px;
        line-height: 185px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        font-size: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: -120px;
    }

    main {
        margin-top: 150px;
        padding: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
```

The body:

```
<div id="header">
    <nav id="main_nav">
        <div class="image">IMAGE</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Nav 1</li>
            <li>Nav 2</li>
            <li>Nav 3</li>
            <li>Nav 4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<main>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore aperiam fugit consequuntur voluptatibus ex, sint iure in, distinctio sed dolorem aspernatur veritatis repellendus dolorum voluptate, animi libero, officiis eveniet accusamus!
</main>
```

I'd like to have the image stick to the left side of the navigation and center them both horizontally (and without overlaying each other as it's currently happening). And is the negative positioning even the right way to move the image?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Also, when showing your attempts and optimizing them for your posts, you might even stumble across the answer yourself! Further, you can show the research you have already done, which can also help all of us. Success!

Comment: @Andreas Oh, I'm very sorry everyone! I updated the first post and added a short example of how i tried to do it but failed horribly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try centering the container using `margin: 0 auto;` and then having the image positioned with a negative top margin. Then position the menu part with a left padding to push past the width of the image.

Comment: I did as you said. I had to play around a bit with the list's padding and the image's margin but I guess it works now. Thanks for your answe, I appreciate that.